# Is there a way to get a thread dump of a GRPC server

Tags: c++, server, grpc

I'm having a GRPC service written in Go that wraps a C++ library.
Now, once in a while, the server hangs on a grpcurl based client call, while it succeeds at other times in sending out a response.

I have tried exporting the grpc traces variable and setting the verbosity to DEBUG, but they didn't seem to help.

Comment: It's not clear from your description whether you are using the gRPC golang library or the gRPC C++ library.  Which is it?

Comment: @MarkD.Roth It's the former (gRPC go lang library).

Comment: You can dump go stack trace using pprof: https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/pprof/